# Angularjs-$ngSource-DELETE: How to get response data which the server side returns?

Tags: angularjs

Why the console.log(response) didn't inculde the response from server. How can I get the "1" or "0" which the SpringMVC return?

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource']);


app.factory('baseRequest', ["$resource", function ($resource) {

    return $resource("/apis/:id/:method/", {method: '@method', id: '@id'}, {

        query: {method: 'get', isArray: false}
    });

}]);


app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "baseRequest", function ($scope, baseRequest) {


    $scope.deleteUser = function (id) {

        baseRequest.delete({method: "deleteUser.req", id: id}, function (response) {

          //I can't get the response data from server side here. 

            console.log(response);

        }, function (error) {

            console.log(error);

        });
    };

}]);
```

Here is my SpringMVC file, it retruns the information "1" or "0"
,but I don't how to get it?

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/deleteUser", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

        System.out.println(id);


        if (userDao.deleteUser(id)) {


            return "1";

        } else {

            return "0";
        }

    }
```

Comment: why you are passing a method variable in the resouce factory ?

Answer (score 0):

the whole code seems wrong to me. Actually you factory should look like this:

```
app.factory('baseRequest', ["$resource", function ($resource) {

return $resource("/apis/:id", { id: '@id'}, {

    query: {method: 'get', isArray: false}
});

}]);
```

and you controller should look like this:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "baseRequest", function ($scope, baseRequest) {


$scope.deleteUser = function (id) {

    baseRequest.delete({id: id}, function (response) {

      //I can't get the response data from server side here. 

        console.log(response);

    }, function (error) {

        console.log(error);

    });
};

}]);
```

When you define a resource to an endpoint, angularjs automatically create the four methods(Verbs) (get, delete, put, post) for you. so you don't need to pass the method name to the web api.

Comment: I am a beginner of Angularjs. But according to  what you suggestted, I do have a confusion about this. How can the client side method 'delete' request to the server side'method  'deleteUser', its have a @RequestMapping like value = "/{id}/deleteUser".